# Add quotation around

Tags: postgis

The result from this query

```
Select pointlayer.geometry from pointlayer
```

return `Point(40 30)`

I need to add quotation marks to the result of my select query so I can use ST_GeomFromText. Something like this
I am hoping a query similar to this..

```
Select (' + pointlayer.geometry + ') from pointlayer
```

Would produce `'Point(40 30)'`

So I can use the geometry like so

```
Select ST_GeomFromText((' + pointlayer.geometry + ')) AS geom from pointlayer
```

Would it be possible to concatonate in the select query to use the ST function?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need it.

```
ST_GeomFromText( pointlayer.geometry ) AS geom from pointlayer
```

should work.

Indeed you shouldn't even need the `st_geomFromText`

```
Select pointlayer.geometry::geometry from pointlayer;
```

That being said, if your column is `text` and not `geometry`, then the column name "geometry" is a poor name.

And just to satisfy your curiosity, you can concatenate string using `||` and to include a `'`, you would write it several times:

```
select '''' || 'I don''t need this!' || '''';
       ?column?
-----------------------
 'I don't need this!'
```

Comment: I seem to be a silly name true. It come from the virtual layer i QGIS. select * from point return one column "geometry". I want to cast it to a geometry column to to a spatial query.

Comment: virtual layers should return a geometry. Are you sure you can't just use it as a geometry?